# How I can get STOMP protocol checkbox option on Websocket sampler

Tags: websocket, jmeter, stomp

I am not getting the STOMP protocol check box option on web socket sampler.

I have downloaded following jar and placed on `/lib/ext`

```
JMeterWebSocketSampler-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
JMeterWebSocketSamplers-1.2.1.jar
jetty-http.jar
jetty-io.jar
jetty-util.jar
websocket-api.jar
websocket-client.jar
websocket-common.jar
```

I have seen some forum STOMP protocol option is there screenshot attached, but for me option is not available.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download clean [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1/) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)
2. Download the following file to **lib/ext** folder of your JMeter installation:

   - [JMeterWebSocketStompSampler-0.2.jar](https://github.com/Fyro-Ing/JMeter-WebSocket-StompSampler/releases/download/0.2/JMeterWebSocketStompSampler-0.2.jar)
3. Download the following files to **lib** folder of your JMeter installation:

   - [websocket-server-9.1.1.v20140108.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-server/9.1.1.v20140108/websocket-server-9.1.1.v20140108.jar)
   - [jetty-io-9.1.1.v20140108.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.1.1.v20140108/jetty-io-9.1.1.v20140108.jar)
   - [jetty-util-9.1.1.v20140108.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.1.1.v20140108/jetty-util-9.1.1.v20140108.jar)
   - [websocket-api-9.1.1.v20140108.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-api/9.1.1.v20140108/websocket-api-9.1.1.v20140108.jar)
   - [websocket-client-9.1.1.v20140108.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-client/9.1.1.v20140108/websocket-client-9.1.1.v20140108.jar)
   - [websocket-common-9.1.1.v20140108.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-common/9.1.1.v20140108/websocket-common-9.1.1.v20140108.jar)
4. Start JMeter
5. You should be able to see the `Stomp Protocol` checkbox and should be able to execute STOMP requests:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks it worked now, please share  If you have any sample test script.

Comment: here is the screenshot of request and response. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SuFljtgG4wrRPdrDLH-3a5VLyGeTQt5L
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1covw0KeqazvUBSo0rQk-lbyNNsiATWDB
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sNODT6bCwuKreckmBXyLXUNdfZZGwkZI

Comment: It worked after downloading the clean jmeter.  I was just skipping the first step of clean install. somehow jmeter loads the manually put lib extensions only once (at the first start)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download that. It is available at the below link;-
https://github.com/Fyro-Ing/JMeter-WebSocket-StompSampler

Check compiled library under releases,
https://github.com/Fyro-Ing/JMeter-WebSocket-StompSampler/releases

Also, cross check below libraries are available in the JMeter\lib\ext folder:

jetty-http-9.1.1.v20140108.jar

jetty-io-9.1.1.v20140108.jar

jetty-util-9.1.1.v20140108.jar

websocket-api-9.1.1.v20140108.jar

websocket-client-9.1.1.v20140108.jar

websocket-common-9.1.1.v20140108.jar

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already copied all the JAR on lib/ext, and I can also able to connection with server but it I didnt get any response from server. screenshot attached on below answers

Comment: If you have any test script please share,here is the screenshot of request and response. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SuFljtgG4wrRPdrDLH-3a5VLyGeTQt5L
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1covw0KeqazvUBSo0rQk-lbyNNsiATWDB
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sNODT6bCwuKreckmBXyLXUNdfZZGwkZI