# How can I test a WebSocket STOMP using JMeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56713295/how-i-can-get-stomp-protocol-checkbox-option-on-websocket-sampler) But things did not work properly because when I try to download JMeterWebSocketStompSampler-0.2.jar, It is not Found. But other jar files are found and are in place, here's a sample of my samplers screenshot attached.
[image]

Are there any suggestions to be able to test a local STOMP ?? I also tried APIC extension in chrome and it is failing, I am attaching an image.
[image]

Any Suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can use [WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers) (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)), some sample code snippets are available in [Using Websocket samplers in JMeter with STOMP](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/issues/39/using-websocket-samplers-in-jmeter-with) plugin issue discussion, for instance this one:

```
String s = "CONNECT\n" +       
       "login:${wsToken}\n" +
                   "passcode:\n" +
                   "accept-version:1.1,1.0\n" +
                   "heart-beat:20000,0\n" +
                   "\n" + 
                   '\0'  // note: NULL char at end
                   ;

vars.put("wsStompData", s);
```